# Text Classification of News Articles Using Spacy

Tags: machine-learning, classification, spacy, text-classification, multilabel-classification

**Dataset** : Csv files containing around **1500** data with columns **(Text,Labels)** where Text is the news article of **Nepali Language** and Label is its genre(Health, World,Tourism, Weather) and so on.

I am using [Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/training#textcat) to train my Text Classification Model. So far, I have converted the dataset to a dataframe which looks like this [image] 
and then into a spacy acceptable format through the code

```
dataset['tuples'] = dataset.apply(
    lambda row: (row['Text'],row['Labels']), axis=1)
training_data = dataset['tuples'].tolist()
```

which gives me the list of tuples in my training dataset like [('text...','label...'),('text...','label...')]

Now, how can I do text classification here?

In the spacy's documentation, I found

```
textcat.add_label("POSITIVE")
textcat.add_label("NEGATIVE")
```

Do we have to add the labels according to the labels or should we use positive/negative as well? Does spacy generate the labels according to our dataset after training or not?

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your own labels. So, in your case:

```
textcat.add_label('Health')
textcat.add_label('World')
textcat.add_label('Tourism')
...
```

`spacy` then will be able to predict only those categories, that you added in the above block of code

There is a special format for training data: each element of your list with data is a tuple that contains:

1. Text
2. Dictionary with one element only. `cats` is a key and another dictionary is a value. That another dictionary contains all your categories as keys and `1` or `0` as values indicating whether this category is correct or not.

So, your data should look like this:

`[('text1', {'cats' : {'category1' : 1, 'category2' : 0, ...}}), 
  ('text2', {'cats' : {'category1' : 0, 'category2' : 1, ...}}), 
  ...]`

Comment: And in the dataset if my data looks like [('text...','label...'),('text...','label...')] Should I represent these multi labels to numbers, or spacy can train it with the labels?

Comment: @SubhaMaharjan I added this to my answer

Comment: Thanks :) This works but now I am not clear how to specify the value of cats.

Comment: @SubhaMaharjan what do you mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62340044/spacy-textcat-score-in-multilabel-classfication I have explained my question here. Also Thank you for the answer above. Really helped.

Comment: @SubhaMaharjan you're welcome. Good luck with your project!